# Laravel group by 1 order by multiple

Tags: laravel, group-by, sql-order-by

I want to get a collection, group it by 1 field, and order it by multiple fields.

Here are things I've tried:

```
    $permission_groups = collect(Permission::orderBy('group', 'asc')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get());
    $permission_groups->groupBy('group');
```

Causes `Trying to get property of non-object`

```
    $permission_groups = Permission::all()->sortBy('group', 'asc')->sortBy('name', 'asc')->groupBy('group');
```

Causes the collection to be sorted and then resorted.

How do I simply order by 2 columns and group it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
$permission_groups = Permission::orderBy('group', 'asc')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get()->groupBy('group');
```